# Semantic React - Form.Select how to use custom array options

Tags: forms, reactjs, web, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

the semantic react docs about From.Select is to give it a prop options that needs to have a specific array like that :

```
const options = [
 { key: 'm', text: 'Male', value: 'male' },
 { key: 'f', text: 'Female', value: 'female' },
]
```

and using it like that :

```
<Form.Field control={Select} label='Gender' options={options} placeholder='Gender' />
```

if i want to use other array with custom keys and values like that for example :

```
const options = [
 { date: 'somedate', title: 'sometitle', },
 { date: 'somedate', title: 'sometitle', },
]
```

i am getting an error about using wrong props

my question is how can i use my own array with this Select Component 
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat you options before sending it to semantic component:

```
import { get, map } from 'lodash'

const reformatOptions = options =>
  map(options, e => ({
    key: get(e, 'date'),
    value: get(e, 'date'),
    text: get(e, 'title'), // (or whatever other format you wish to use)
  }))
```

And then pass the `options=reformatOptions(options)` to your semantic component